# appending schema name in query in oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have one enviornment in which `queries` containing more than 100 `tables`. now i need to access same query in read only environment. so i need to use `<schema_name>.<table_name>` in read only env. This is read only env so i can not create `synonyms` for all.

instead of writing schema name in prefix of each table, Is there any short cut for it. i am just guessing if anything is possible? They all belongs to same schema.

Comment: If all tables belong to the same schema, what's the point in preceding their names with schema name? Why don't you omit it, completely?

Comment: sir,this is read only schema, we have only read access. but table doest not belongs to us. they have not created any public synonym for it.

Comment: Aha, someone else owns those tables.OK. Did you try what chegancasb suggested in their answer?

Comment: ya, actually even alter session priviledge i do not have. any excel short tric or any query like concat etc?

Comment: I mean can i modify queries in some smarter way? even java or unix code will be helpful

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't know. Synonyms are most obvious. See whether the owner can provide them for you (private, not public ones).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It will set your session environment to the specified schema and as consequence, no need to provide the `<schema_name>` prefix.

`ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = <schema_name>;`